# How to choose where to append data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, append, fs

How do I choose where to append data with fs.appendFileSync()?

My current code:

```
var fd = fs.openSync('test.js', 'a');
fs.appendFileSync('test.js', "/**/");
fs.closeSync(fd);
```

This just appends the data at the end of the file. The options object gives me no way to choose where to append it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.appendFileSync()` can only append data to the end of the file.  It does not have the option you are asking for.

In fact, the only way (with a normal file system) to insert data into the middle of a file is to rewrite data that is in the file to move it later in the file and then write to the block where you want the new data to go.  For this, you would use `fs.read()` and `fs.write()` passing it the desired file positions.